# Combine two lists into one list Racket

Tags: list, recursion, compare, racket

I have a question:

I have two list of numbers for example (list1 3 6 7) and (list2 1 6 4 7). Now I have to combine both into (list3 1 3 4). So 6 and 7 are both in list1 and list2. List3 contains all numbers which occur only once. I hope u get what i mean if not just ask me :s!
Here my start:

```
(define (diff list1 list2)
  (cond
    [(empty? list1) list2] ;; If list1 was empty return directly list2
    [(empty? list2) list1] ;; If list2 was empty return directly list1
    [else
      (???
```

I know that I have to compare first list1 with every number in list2 and then recursiv again. But how do I programm it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different, hopefully less-tricky, implementation. (It's O(n), but it requires both of the incoming lists to be sorted; in comparison, Óscar's implementation does not required sorted lists, but it's O(n²).)

```
(define (diff lhs rhs)
  (let loop ((result '())
             (lhs lhs)
             (rhs rhs))
    (cond ((null? lhs) (append-reverse result rhs))
          ((null? rhs) (append-reverse result lhs))
          (else (let ((a (car lhs))
                      (b (car rhs)))
                  (cond ((< a b) (loop (cons a result) (cdr lhs) rhs))
                        ((< b a) (loop (cons b result) lhs (cdr rhs)))
                        (else (loop result (cdr lhs) (cdr rhs)))))))))
```

Example:

```
> (diff '(3 6 7) '(1 4 6 7))
(1 3 4)
```

`append-reverse` is from [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html), so in Racket you have to `(require srfi/1)`.

Comment: `s/ordered/sorted/` ;)

Comment: Hey nice but we never used the keywords "car" or "loop" so I dont think I'm allowed to use this :( But really thanks for your help :)!

Comment: @Tobias I nearly always answer questions in the way a professional Schemer would code it, not in a "homework-approved" way. However, `car` may be spelt `first` in your course.