# Output Elements in List That Are Not Incommon

Tags: scheme

I've created a function that should return the elements that the two lists do not have in common. Currently, they are outputting exactly what is passed into it. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
(define (findDifference lst1 lst2)
    (if (null? lst1) lst2
    (cons (car lst1) (findDifference (cdr lst1) lst2))))

(findDifference '(2 3 4 (2 3) 2 (4 5)) '(2 4 (4 5))
```

Current Output: `(2 3 4 (2 3) 2 (4 5) 2 4 (4 5))`
Desired Output: `(3 (2 3))`

Comment: You could brute force your way through this: Iterate over the first list, check if the second list contains this element, if not, add it to result. Then to the same for the second list. Note that this algorithm runs in exponential time. An optimization could be to create two hashsets for each element which would result in amortized sequential time.

Comment: PS: The term for what you are looking for is "symmetric difference".

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer I am new to scheme, so not sure how to approach this. Could you expand? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of two lists. Try this:

```
(define (diff list1 list2)
  (union (complement list1 list2)
         (complement list2 list1)))
```

Using the following helper procedures:

```
(define (union list1 list2)
  (cond ((null? list1) list2)
        ((member (car list1) list2) (union (cdr list1) list2))
        (else (cons (car list1) (union (cdr list1) list2)))))

(define (complement list1 list2)
  (cond ((null? list1) '())
        ((member (car list1) list2) (complement (cdr list1) list2))
        (else (cons (car list1) (complement (cdr list1) list2)))))
```

Also notice that if you're using Racket you can simply use the built-in [`set-symmetric-difference`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fset..rkt%29._set-symmetric-difference%29%29) procedure for the same effect. For example:

```
(diff '(2 3 4 (2 3) 2 (4 5)) '(2 4 (4 5)))
=> '(3 (2 3))
```

Comment: I am a bit confused on how to call this. I've tried to call it by using diff, union and complement with the list.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I get the following error: "Error: execute: unbound symbol: "empty?" [complement, complement, diff, complement, union, diff, complement, complement, diff, complement]"

Comment: For completeness sake: in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28282271/201359), there's a fast implementation that works fine for sorted lists as long as the elements can be compared (not your case, because the elements are lists).

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like homework and I do not want to spoil the fun, here is the brute force algorithm, with some bits left out. If you are really stuck I will give you the full source.

```
(define (sym-diff xs ys)
  ;; Since we have the helper function we can determine all the elements that are in the first list, 
  ;; but not in the second list.
  ;; Then we can pass this intermediate result to the second call to sym-diff-helper. 
  ;;This will return us all the elements that are in the second list but not the first.
  (let ((in-first-not-second ...))
    (sym-diff-helper ys xs in-first-not-second)))

;; This function will return all the elements from the first list that are not in the second list!
(define (sym-diff-helper xs ys acc)
  (cond
    ;; If the first list is empty we have checked it.
    (...
     acc)
    ;; If the first list is not empty yet, check if the first element 
    ;; is in the second list.
    ;; If so, discard it and continue with the rest of the list.
    ((member ... ...)
     (sym-diff-helper ... ... ...)
    ;; If the first element of the first list is not in the second list, 
    ;; add it to the accumulator and continue with the rest of the list.
    (else
     (sym-diff-helper ... ... ...)))

(sym-diff-helper '(1 2 3) '(2 3 4) '())
;; == (1)
(sym-diff-helper '(1 2 (3 4) 5) '(2 3 4) '())  
;; == (5 (3 4) 1)


(sym-diff '(2 3 4 (2 3) 2 (4 5)) '(2 4 (4 5)))
;; == ((2 3) 3)
```

Note that I have chosen to use `member`. There are a few other search functions but they were not well suited in this case. Hence, I left it there. More info on the search functions can be found here: [http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28part.*.List*.Searching%29](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28part._.List_.Searching%29)

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if I can get it from here!

Comment: I'm sure you will find it! Good luck!